# Unsubscribe Pusher channel

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pusher

I'm new to using `Pusher` with my `Rails` app.
Everything is working fine and i'm now able to subscribe to channels and receive `JSON` message.

But i want to make an button where i can unsubscribe from a specific channel.

I have tried this

```
<button onclick="unsubscribe_channcel('test_channel')">Unsubscribe</button>

<script>
  function unsubscribe_channcel(channelName) {
  var pusher = new Pusher('APP KEY');
  pusher.unsubscribe(channelName);
};
</script>
```

But it do not work. If i look in the debug console when i press the button all that happens is that it make a new connection and i keep receiving messages from the "test_channel".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unsubscribe to the channel on the same instance of the `Pusher` object that you subscribed to the channel on e.g.

```
<button onclick="subscribe_channel('test_channel')">Subscribe</button>
<button onclick="unsubscribe_channel('test_channel')">Unsubscribe</button>

<script src="http://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
  Pusher.log = function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
  };

  var YOUR_APP_KEY = "1afb3f8f61eb29da86df";
  var pusher = new Pusher(YOUR_APP_KEY);

  function subscribe_channel( channelName ) {
    pusher.subscribe( channelName );
  }

  function unsubscribe_channel(channelName) {
    pusher.unsubscribe(channelName);
  }
</script>
```

You can find a working example of this code here: http://jsbin.com/camul/1/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But im getting this error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined" according to this, is it possible to use the unsubscribe. but it dosen't seems like its working. https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_public_channels

Comment: I've updated the code example to replace a couple of small errors. I've also added a link to a working example of the code. `pusher.unsubscribe` is definitely present and works as described in the docs.

Comment: "Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined": this error is showed when channelName is invalid.